# Kill long running thread within specified time

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, transactions, spring-transactions

We are trying to import an object (For instance `objectA`) in the database which will firstly import itself and then its child objects (For instance `objectAA`, `objectAB`, `objectAC` etc). We start a local transaction using DefaultTransactionDefinition, execute the method importing object and then commit/rollback the transaction. Method importing the object will perform the following actions,

1. Retrieving the stored procedure from the database.
2. Execute the query to import the object’s content.
3. Stores and processes the response returned by the query.
4. Performs all the above actions for child objects.

I want to interrupt this method in case it is taking too long. I tried following techniques,

1. Use thread to import object. But there is no specific place where thread importing the object will be blocked in the method, so, `interrupt()` cannot be used to STOP the thread.
2. There are multiple database query’s in the method, so, `cancel()` cannot be used to STOP query and cause the method to return.
3. Currently, I am looking into `setTimeout()` method of defaultTransactionDefinition to terminate the transaction after some specified time which will in turn cause the method to return. But it cannot terminate the method in between.

Is there any way to terminate the method while it is executing and then commit/rollback the transaction accordingly?

Comment: Just to clarify, you use Spring's defaultTransactionDefinition ???

Comment: Yes I am using Spring's defaultTransactionDefinition.